# How to get server reply after sending a mail using smtplib SMTP.sendmail

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a program to send mail using python smtplib. I have the mail sending part working fine, but I also need to capture the server return message after a mail has been sent. For example postfix returns the following message after a mail has been queueed:

```
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EB83821273B\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EB83821273B
data: (250, '2.0.0 Ok: queued as EB83821273B')
```

What I am really interested is the error code (250) and the queue id (EB83821273B). I can print these if I set set_debuglevel(1), but I need to capture this in a variable for further logging and processing.

thanks and regards,

raj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the [sendmail](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) method on an `SMTP` instance, then it will return

> a dictionary, with one entry for each
>   recipient that was refused. Each entry
>   contains a tuple of the SMTP error
>   code and the accompanying error
>   message sent by the server.

if you use the [docmd](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.docmd) method on the same class, the it will return

> a 2-tuple composed of a numeric response code and the actual response line (multiline responses are joined into one long line.)

Comment: It's also worth noting that this method may raise the following exceptions: SMTPHeloError, SMTPRecipientsRefused, SMTPSenderRefused or SMTPDataError

Comment: If I use docmd method I will have to basically reimplement sendmail command by command right?

Comment: The `sendmail` returns an empty dictionary when the status code is 250 (all goes well). So it seems it's impossible to get the server response when you are using `sendmail` and no errors happened.

Comment: I get empty dict in response but I dont see email in my mail :(