# Python smtplib sending mail using docmd

Tags: python, smtplib

I currently have an smtplib client using sendmail. I need to trap the message id given to the sent message by the receiving server - and from what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820603/how-to-get-server-reply-after-sending-a-mail-using-smtplib-smtp-sendmail) I need to use smtplib's `docmd` command. What I've worked out so far is fairly easy:

```
import smtplib
svr = smtplib.SMTP("localhost",26)
r = svr.docmd("ehlo", "me")
r = svr.docmd("mail from:","me@home.com")
r = svr.docmd("rcpt to:","you@work.com")
r = svr.docmd("data","")
```

But now when I try to do `svr.docmd("send","Hello there")` it just hangs? Similarly, I assume I should do `r = svr.docmd("send",".")` to send the terminating "." character to send the mail, and get the server response (in theory including msg id!) as part of the returned tuple?

Would really appreciate it if someone could point me at where I'm going wrong in these final steps?

Or am I completely misunderstanding - is using docmd NOT the way to get the server response when the mail is sent? If I am wrong, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smtplib`module cannot work like that. It is a higher level library and you should **not** try to send simple mail with `docmd`. `docmd` only helps to pass special commands. You should simply use :

```
svr.sendmail('me@home', 'you@work', 'msg')
```

If you really want to do it *the hard way*, you should send all the data in only single `docmd` :

```
...
r = svr.docmd("data")
r = svr.docmd("line 1\r\nline 2\r\n.\r\n")
```

That way it a a complete command that receives its SMTP response

Edit :

The return of low-level commands is the content of the SMTP response. The [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) specifies that this replies consist in a 3 digit number followed by an textual explaination. It can be multiline if the number is followed by a `-`. But all that is hidden from you by smtplib module. The main point of interest if you use low level commands is first digit from the number :

```
1yz   Positive Preliminary reply
2yz   Positive Completion reply
3yz   Positive Intermediate reply
4yz   Transient Negative Completion reply
5yz   Permanent Negative Completion reply
```

If it is 4 or 5 the command was rejected, 1,2, or 3 it was successful

If you use directly sendmail command, if you do not get an exception, the mail was successfuly received by the server and accepted for at least on recipient. The return value is *a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused. Each entry contains a tuple of the SMTP error code and the accompanying error message sent by the server* (extract from the module documentation).

I advice you to use the `sendmail` command unless you want to learn the SMTP protocol or have other special requirement.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta ... I appreciate that "sendmail" is the better way of sending mail, but that returns nothing from the remote server. As I understand it, docmd returns a tuple which will (hopefully!) contain the reference the server had given the message... Unless you can advise a better way of getting this?

Comment: @SteveHall: SMTP protocol has no provision to return a message reference to sender. See my edit.

Comment: I feared you might say that.... but desperately hoped you wouldnt.... Bizarrely I got your docmd solution above working (although obviously not returning the ref I wanted)- I actually had the message successfully delivered, despite the docmd sequence returning a 5xx... Anyway, all that's fairly irrelevent I guess .... Many thanks for your time and help :)