# using docmd to receive queue-id of a mail from smtp server

Tags: python, smtp, sendmail, jython

I have written a code in jython 2.5, which uses the smtplib sendmail to send mail over a smtp server. Below is a simple snippet of the code

```
        mail = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    mail['Subject'] = mail_subject
    mail['FROM']=UstrSender
    mail['To']=UstrReceivers
    mail['Cc']=UstrCC
    mail_p2=MIMEText(mail_html, 'html', 'utf-8')
    mail.attach(mail_p2)

    #Connection to SMTP
    #Enter SMTP Server Details, In case your server do require authentication modify authentication parameter below and uncomment
    s = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    #s.sendmail(UstrSender, [UstrReceivers, UstrCC], mail.as_string())
    sendmail_return = s.sendmail(UstrSender, [UstrReceivers, UstrCC], mail.as_string())
```

Now, the smtp server mentioned is a cluster of 3 individual servers and there is a lag at times on one of these servers because of a long queue of requests. To identify such issues and the culprit server, need to have a generic script to identify the queue id of the message being sent. Kindly, help on the same, if using docmd we can create such a command to get the queue id of the submitted email.

I tried getting a response from sendmail itself, but since the mail is eventually sent, there is no return from the command.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907546/send-raw-email-from-python-and-retrieve-sendmail-queueid

Comment: How to subclass smtplib and override sendmail ?? haven't really tried inheritance in python !

Comment: I have been able to figure out how to get the queueid, a simple s.set_debuglevel(1), is able to give me that .. but need to figure out how to print these replies from server in a file ?? I initially though it would be getting captured on the standard output but it is not .. kindly help ?