# Printing SMTP server replies onto a file/variable

Tags: python, logging, stdout, jython

I have written a code in python to send an email using SMTP. Initially my issue was to get the queued of the generated mail. Details of the same are at below link

[using docmd to receive queue-id of a mail from smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998641/using-docmd-to-receive-queue-id-of-a-mail-from-smtp-server)

The issue is somewhat resolved by using

```
s.set_debuglevel(1)
```

but the issue that remains is to print these debug logs onto a file or maybe a variable in code itself. I initially thought these logs are printed on the stdout and tried using it but wasn't successful. Kindly, provide your insights here.

[SMTP server replies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd4E0.jpg)

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: you can use module [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to create own logging system and configure it to save in file. I don't know if smtplib also use logging module but logging as default doesn't write in file.

Comment: using `import smtplib ; print( smtplib.__file__ )` you can get path to this module and you can open it in editor to see source coude. You will see it display using `sys.stderr`. If you assign file to `sys.stderr` then you should get messages in file.

Comment: or you can create own class based on class SMTP  - `class MySMTP(smtplib.SMTP)` -  and overwrite `_print_debug` to write in file.

Comment: its being written to stderr but not working for me .. I tried using "from cStringIO import StringIO" .. old_stdout = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = StringIO() .. s = smtplib.SMTP() …..out = sys.stderr.getvalue()
sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = old_stdout

print out.upper() … but doesn't work for me .. following link works on the same issue but since I am using python 2.5 , its not working for me :( … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294251/capture-debug-output-from-python-smtplib/34682107#34682107

Comment: see source code - it uses `_print_debug` to display it. You can create class with own `_print_debug` which will write in file.

Comment: this is jython 2.5.1 that I am using, and there is no method with the name _print_debug in this instead, sendmail method is using getreply method to print replies from the smtp server