# Python send SMTP and get server response code

Tags: python, response, smtplib

Now I am able to send the email through python using smtplib, however is there any way I can identify the email bounce back or blacklist issue through the response code returned from SMTP like 200, 504, 500 etc?

Current part of code:

```
try:
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
    smtpObj.close()


except SMTPResponseException as e:
    error_code = e.smtp_code
    error_messsage = e.smtp_error
    print(str(error_code) + ' - ' + str(error_messsage))
```

Comment: You should inspect the dictionary returned by the `sendmail` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820603/how-to-get-server-reply-after-sending-a-mail-using-smtplib-smtp-sendmail. should be informative

Comment: @snakecharmerb, it still return empty dic even though the email get bounce back and I received the NDR.

Comment: If the return dict is empty then the server is accepting the email and the rejection is taking place later.

Comment: yes, I am trying to catch the bounce back / rejection